# Add "Chapter" to the table of contents. Report class

Tags: table-of-contents, tocloft

I currently have my ToC formatted exactly as I need it except I need the word "Chapter" to appear before the chapter number.

```
i.e:  I want to see  Chapter 1:  Title
      instead of             1:  Title.
```

After reading the PDF regarding the `tocloft` package it seems that the correct way to take care of this is with the command:

```
\renewcommand{\cftchappresnum}{Chapter }
```

citing pg. 11 of the document.  When I do this I see no result; nothing in my document changes.  I have seen others resolve this issue in a similar way so I am very perplexed as to why it is yielding me no result.  Is it possible that the issue is that I am using the `report` class?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb, amsthm, fancyhdr, enumerate, comment, titlesec, tocloft, lipsum, titletoc}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\contentsname}{~~~~~~TABLE OF CONTENTS}

\renewcommand{\cftpartdotsep}{\cftdotsep}
\renewcommand{\cftchapdotsep}{\cftdotsep}
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftsecdotsep}}

\renewcommand{\cftchappresnum}{\chaptername~} 
\setlength{\cftchapnumwidth}{6em}

\tableofcontents
\thispagestyle{fancy}

\chapter{First Chapter}
\chapter{Second Chapter}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Use `\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftchappresnum}{\chaptername~}
\setlength{\cftchapnumwidth}{6em}`.

Comment: Werner, thank you for your help and reply.  I have followed your instruction but still see no change in my document sadly.

Comment: You need to supply us with a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that replicates the problem (*please* click the link and read the post). Trim your document bit-by-bit until you have it small enough to include your code in your original post. Then we can copy-and-paste it, compile it, and see exactly what you're seeing.

Comment: However, there is space added between the chapter number and chapter title but the word 'Chapter' does not appear.

Comment: Werner, thanks for your patience and help so far.  Sorry, I am quite bad at this.

Comment: Don't mix your ToC-related packages. Remove [`titletoc`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titletoc) (since it conflicts with [`tocloft`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tocloft)).

Comment: When I remove either of titletoc or tocloft I can not get it to compile; it no longer outputs anything.

Comment: No. Keep the `tocloft` package and delete the `titletoc` package. Compile more than once, since the ToC depends on at least two compiles to start with.

Comment: Doing as you said Werner still would not allow me to compile.  I was able to resolve this issue by changing the order of titletoc and tocloft as they appear in the packages section at the beginning of the document.  Thanks for your time.